# Fatal error: Class Soap Client not found in

Tags: php, apache

I have an apache 2.4, php 5.6.19 and win10 running but I receice an error message
Class Soap Client not found in....
I set the **extension=php_soap.dll** and e**xtension_dir="D\ProgramFiles\PHP\ext"** and checked also if the dll is availible in the directory. Yes it is.

Also phpinfo() don't show soap infos.
what can be the reason?

Comment: D:\ProgramFiles\PHP\ext (missing `:`)

Comment: Check your http servers error log, it will tell you why the extension fails to load.

Comment: The php.ini was not on the right place that was the reason. I changed the development.ini to a ini with win 10 but it stays as development ini. So I created a new php.ini with an editor and copy all into it. Than it works